# Django - count up timer

Tags: javascript, html, django, timer, django-templates

Hey I want to implement a timer which starts if I go to this template:

```
{% block content %}


 <h3>C-Test</h3>

  <p>In the following text, some of the word endings have been replaced by a gap. The gap is approximately half of the word, e.g. if you see 3 letters, you need to add another 3-4 letters to complete the word. Try your best.</p>

  <form action="results" id=results method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="cTestFormat" value="{{ text }}">

    <div class="ctest">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{  forms }}{{ ende }}
    </div>

    <div class="command">
      <button type="submit" name="ctest_submit">Submit solution</button>
    </div>
  </form>


{% endblock %}
```

and ends if I click on the Submit solution button.

I want it saved into the `POST` request so I can return the time in my `results.html`.

This is my `results.html`:

```
{% block content %}


<h3>C-Test</h3>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <p>You got {{ richtige }} right!!!!!!</p>
  <p>But {{ falsche }} wrong :(</p>

  <p> {{ testresult|safe }}</p>


{% endblock %}
```

Ive read that you need some scripting language for a timer but I dont have any experience with it. Is there any other method with django to do this or do I need something like javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of one using JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    var sec = 0;
    function pad ( val ) { return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; }
    setInterval( function(){
        $("#seconds").html(pad(++sec%60));
        $("#minutes").html(pad(parseInt(sec/60,10)));
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="minutes"></span>:<span id="seconds"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can I just use this code in my template or do I need to download some requirements first?